# How do I get rid of the white spaces in this String[]?

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

Originally, I was just trying to get the characters in a string. I used split to isolate my characters to count them. I have my characters, but I can't get rid of the spaces it's printing in the array.

I tried everything that I saw in other stack overflow posts.

```
public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "+d+=3=+s+";
    String[] alpha = str.split("[^a-z]");
    for(int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
      alpha[i] = alpha[i].replaceAll("\\s+", "");
         System.out.println(alpha[i]);
    }

       // System.out.println(alpha.length);
    }

}
```

I'm just trying to count characters without spaces and using more loops.

Comment: There are **no spaces** in `str`, so there are no spaces in `alpha`, so there is nothing for `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` to do. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "+d+=3=+s+";
        System.out.println(str);

        str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println("count "+str.length());
    }

}
```

Output will be

```
ds
count 2
```

output doesn't contains whitespace so you can get rid of loops

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the **blank lines** in your output, those are not *spaces*, they are **empty strings** in the `alpha` array.

Since you regex only matching a single character, the `split` operation will create empty entries, i.e. a *plain* split will produce the following array:

```
{ "", "d", "", "", "", "", "s", "" }
```

Since `split` by default removes trailing empty strings, what you actually get is:

```
{ "", "d", "", "", "", "", "s" }
```

As you can see, there are **no spaces** anywhere.

You can remove most of the empty strings by changing `"[^a-z]"` to `"[^a-z]+"`, so multiple consecutive non-letters will be a single separator, which will give you:

```
{ "", "d", "s" }
```

To remove the leading empty string, remove the leading non-letters from the original string first:

```
String[] alpha = str.replaceFirst("[^a-z]+", "").split("[^a-z]+");
```

That will give you:

```
{ "d", "s" }
```

Which of course will eliminate all the blank lines in your output:

```
d
s
```

And you can remove that `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` call, since it's not doing anything.